# How to update a single composer package?

Tags: php, composer-php, packagist

I know that I can use `composer update vendor/package` but here's my case.

Composer is very slow when updating, I have around 6 packages installed and one local vcs package being loaded from a local folder. When I run `composer update` even for that specific local package, composer connects to Packagist to look for other updates and this process is very slow, I don't know if it's my computer or my internet. Is there a way I can tell composer to just update the package from local folder when I run `composer update local/package` without contacting Packagist and running through all the heavy json files it downloads?

**Note:**
I know how to load a local composer package. It's loading perfectly, it's just that I'm looking for a way to tell composer just to load the local package without contacting Packagist.

```
"repositories": [
   {
     "type": "vcs",
     "url": "../local/package"
   }
],
```

My problem is that it's slow to contact Packagist. Running `composer update local/package -vvv` Shows that it still downloads json files from packagist even if it's told to update just `local/package`.

Comment: [Composer: installing package from local git repository](http://marekkalnik.tumblr.com/post/22929686367/composer-installing-package-from-local-git)

Comment: @MarkBaker thank you, but it's not what I was asking. I updated the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple ways of speeding the Composer fetch up:

1. define a custom repo, which points to a local path and `install` with `--prefer-source`

   ```
   "repositories": [
       {
           "type":"vcs",
           "url":"/path/to/your/local/package/packageA"
       }
   ],
   "require":{
       "package/packageA" : "dev-master"
   }
   ```

   Follow-up trick: if you exactly know the `type` of the repo, then specify it!

   In other words: do not use `"type":"vcs"` if you can specify `"type":"git"` or `"type":"svn"`. Composer will skip running through all the repo adapters to figure the correct one out.
2. you could setup Satis and define only the required packages for your project and their dependencies (`"require-dependencies": "true"`). This acts as a package proxy in front of packagist. You would simply fetch from the local Satis mirror/proxy.

---

Give this a try, to disable the default Packagist repository:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "packagist": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jens, but I was looking for how to tell composer not to contact Packagist when updating the local package. I updated the question.

Comment: Updated my answer: please disable packagist with `packagist: false`.

Comment: Adding `packagist: false` solved the problem, but I have to remove it every time I was to update other packages and add it back again when I want to just update local. I think that composer should add the functionality of detecting when a package is local, if it is, no need to call packagist.com. Thanks anyway, solved.

Comment: Glad i could help.. your idea about the detection and not calling packagist is good.