# Composer: how to let composer to know that I have the package locally already?

Tags: composer-php

I know that we can always install a package via command:

```
composer require packageA
```

But I don't know if you guys ever have a situation like this:

You want to install a big size package "packageB" that your teammate added to composer.json and your wifi is slow so composer would take very very long to get the packageB. Then you have an idea:

> "Maybe I try get the packageB zip from my teammate via flash drive and paste
>   it into my project."

And you did that, the package works as expected. Wonderful!
But then, you think again:

> What if now I want to do the composer update other packages in my
>   project?

You try:

```
composer update
```

and then, what happen is composer will get the package again because you didn't use "composer install" or "composer update" to install packageB so composer doesn't know you have it.

(Sorry for the long explanation).
So my question is:
**How do we let composer know that we have the package already so composer don't re-download the package again?** Or this is the behavior of composer and I must always use "composer install/update", there is no other way?

> And sorry, change to another wifi or find a faster internet connection is really not what I'm looking for. And I also know that we can install the package locally (see here: [How to update a single composer package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253843/how-to-update-a-single-composer-package)).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If we don't want to use `repositories`.

In my knowledge, the only option is to update you `composer.json` and composer.lock. Friend give you version 1.2 to vendor? Write in exactly version in `composer.json` and for `composer.lock`, you will need data from your friend too.

Run install then.

Should check, but not download any file. Still, problem is that all required libraries by this library, could be updated - you can only write down exactly version of them in file.

As default, I think, the didn't predict scenarios for that way.

This is the only solution for you, i know should work.

Answer (score 0):

Composer does use caching heavily to reduce the amount of data to download. However this does not remove the need to download the package at least once.

Basically Composer has two modes to download: `--prefer-dist` will try to obtain a download URL for an archive file, and `--prefer-source` will try to obtain a copy of the version control system being used.

Both variants put the result into Composer's cache directory.

Over time you'll collect a couple of archive files locally, which allow for quick switches back and forth between existing version downloads, and newer versions will have to be downloaded once.

Also you can clone a git repository once, and Composer will try to reuse it when updating, by simply fetching new commits and checking out the appropriate tags. This still requires to clone the repository once.

You can work around cloning the repository by manually placing it at the correct spot, either by physically putting it there, or by symlinking the correct vendor directory. You can also make Composer aware of an official copy by adding the local copy as an entry to `repositories`. This will add this source to the existing collection of packages available from Packagist.